# How to dragged an image into JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drag-and-drop, jpanel

Currently I use this code:

```
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            try {
                repaint();
                getGraphics().drawImage(TreeDrag.obj.getImg(), getMousePosition().x, getMousePosition().y, null);
            } catch (HeadlessException | IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }

        }
```

in my JPanel class. Anyhow the result is this:[Gif1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AGzB.gif)

if I remove `repaint()` method the result is: [Gif2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHoHd.gif)

The image to drag is a BufferedImage Object

My question is: How I can do the drag without flickering or snake effects?

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how the paint mechanism works in Java. To explain your problem, you need to understand these points:

- When you want to paint something permanently, you should override the paintComponent() method of your component to draw the stuff you want. So for your purpose, you should store the new image location in the panel, and call drawImage(image, newLocation.x, newLocation.y) in the panel's paintComponent() method.
- When you try to getGraphics() and paint something to it, the stuff you paint will appear immediately, but it will be cleared at next round paint occurs. It is because every round of paint will clear all old painted stuff and ask all component to paint new stuff again.
- When you trigger repaint(), you request for a new round of paint, this request is scheduled and coalesce which does not happen immediately, but is guaranteed to happen sometime later. You should always call repaint() instead of calling getGraphics().doSomething(), not to mentioned that getGraphics() may return null if the component is not showing.
- This explains why with repaint(), the image will flicker, because your call to getGraphics().drawImage() force it to draw something immediately, then you triggered a new round of paint(), which cleared old content, but you does not provide something new to draw. This caused the image shown then image cleared effect.
- But if without repaint(), you forced image at new position to draw immediately, but old content never cleared, caused the snake effect.